# Moment Generating Function - Poisson?

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, poisson-distribution, moment-generating-functions

Problem: If  $MX(t)=e^{−5(1−et)}$ , find $V(X)$.

Also find: $P(X=3)$

My first intuition is that this would follow the Poisson rule: $M(t)=e^{\lambda(e^t-1)}$

This would mean that $\lambda=E(X)=-5?$

I am not sure how to get $E(X^2)$ so that I can finish the equation $V(X)=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$.

For the $P(X=3)$, it would appear that This is the MGF of the following discrete $rv$ is as follows:

$$X =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x=-5$ } \\
0,  & \text{if $x=0$ } 
\end{cases}
$$

So I don't know that I'm working through this part correctly either.

Comment: Do you mean $-5(1-e^t)$?

Comment: No that is what the formula is...

Comment: Then it's unlikely to be correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MGF of the Poisson as you have written would imply that $\lambda = 5$. The MGF is exactly what it sounds like, a generating function for the moments. $M^{(k)}(0) = E(X^k)$. Thus $M''(0) - (M'(0))^2 = \text{var}(X)$. You can show that this implies that $\text{var}(X) = 5$.

To find $P(X = 3)$, it is better to use the distribution itself
$$ P(X = x) = \frac{e^{-5}5^x}{x!}. $$

Comment: Thank you for your help!